# Gravity Forms - Entering text in a field to also appear in another field without a page reload

Tags: php, gravity-forms-plugin

How to enter text in one field to then appear in another field without reloading the page.

I have a page with a php form with two text fields and a submit button. When clicking the submit button, a pop-up Gravity Form appears to enter extra details. I need the information entered in the first two php text fields to appear in two text boxes on the Gravity Form pop-up without a reload.

Is this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, but only using JavaScript. These are the steps:

1. You need to add an event listener to the submit button. E.g. `document.querySelector('.class-of-submit').addEventListener('click', function(){ /* code here */ });`
2. Once the event fires, you then need to target the input field(s) that contain the data you wish to access. For example, `var enteredText = document.querySelector('.class-name').value`.
3. Then sent the value of the pop-up field(s) like so: `document.querySelector('.class-of-target').value = enteredText;`

That's pretty much it. You'll want to add way more logic to the above (check elements exists and that the fields are not empty), but hopefully this will get you started.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a codeless solution, check out my [Gravity Forms Copy Cat](https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-copy-cat/) plugin. It allows you to auto-copy the value entered in almost any field to any other field.